# How do I configure a home router to block traffic to and from specific geographic regions?

Tags: firewalls, router

My mom keeps typing in wrong URLs with typos and getting sent to Chinese typosquatting malware or fraud sites, so I want to configure my home router to block all traffic to and from China as much as possible.

Did some research on this and none of the search results are conclusive. It's possible the instructions vary by router.

The solution doesn't have to be 100%. In fact, some of the search results I found hinted that perfect geographic blocking is impossible because the blocking tables would be too large. For my purposes, blocking >= 95% of China should be sufficient protection.

Due diligence searching: I see a lot of questions and no really good answers.

https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+ban+all+traffic+to+and+from+china+on+a+home+router&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=LiwIXOmmLrKb_QbbgYLIDw&q=how+to+configure+geographic+site+banning+on+a+home+router

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=SywIXMLpMsae_Qaf3qLgAQ&q=how+do+i+configure+my+home+router+to+block+china

Most jarring is the complete absence of specific step-by-step instructions on how to configure this for beginners who have no clue where to start. That's what I'm looking for: "How to configure geographic web traffic blocking on a home router for dummies".

Something else that further makes the search difficult is that most of the questions are framed in the context of web site operators who want to block geographic regions known to cause trouble on the Web (usually Russia, China, and sometimes parts of Eastern Europe). I'm looking for the reverse - block all websites and traffic to/from known generally malicious regions.

If the instructions are specific to each router, post a comment and I'll reply with the type of my router.

Another alternative is setting up a firewall program on her computer set up to block China and other known bad-actor countries as needed.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you're looking for step-by-step instructions then you have definitely come to the wrong place.  Also, step-by-step instructions are impossible to provide without knowing your router model number.

Comment: I'm not aware of any home routers which are capable of geo-blocking. Moreover, there is no one single type of home router and no single kind of user interface which makes universal step-by-step instructions covering all possible routers impossible. To find out if your specific router supports such configuration and how it should be used please consult the router-specific documentation which you should have either as document, is included as online-help in the router or can be downloaded from the router vendors support site.

Comment: If your router supports OpenWRT, they have modules for this. You will need to flash OpenWRT, install custom modules, and configure iptables by hand. Or you can use cleanbrowsing.org or opendns filtering, it should help.

Comment: Also consider instructing your mom not to type URLs, but use better and safer options like googling (and then click the relevant result) or use safe bookmarks that you already verified

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a geo-lookup/block service with your router (probably you do not for a home router) then you could block based on the IP ranges assigned to China.  This is something you can search on google.  There is a list here http://lite.ip2location.com/china-ip-address-ranges

Note:  There are a lot of ip ranges and to implement this non-horribly-painfully I hope your router/firewall supports a bulk import of ranges ( the site I linked will export a csv of the ranges).